# Entity Framework - How to pass complex type/table type to a function

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Do you know if it's possible to pass as argument a complex type/table type to tabled-value function with EF?

I've followed [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/table-valued-function-in-entity-framework5.aspx) example but seems to work only with primary types. I need to have a function that accepts as a parameter a user-defined table type.

Basic example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunc]
    (@funcArgument dbo.MyCustomDbType READONLY) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT * 
        FROM @funcArgument
```

LE:  I want this function to return `IQueryable<TResult>` and to be used in Linq queries (join operations).

Like this:

```
var queryResult = from x in dbContext.Table1
                  join f in dbContext.MyFunc(argument) on x.Key equals f.Key
                  select x;
```

Comment: It is a good question. Sadly it shows a lack of searching because, while interesting (and cudos for asking it - many developers never get that far) it is not only possible, but also well documented and asked here multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TomTom. The purpose of my question was not clear enough from the beginning, so I would like to explain the entire context. 
I don't want just to call the function and get the result (I did that). I want this function to return IQuerable<TResult> and to be used in Linq queries (join operations)

Comment: @TomTom and I appreciated your reply, I don't understand why you got upset. I realized that my question was not complete so I added additional info.

Comment: @TomTom, you've been overzealous when you closed my question as duplicate. I'm not the first and not the last one that edits a question in order to add additional info. My question has not been answered...

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question as this is asking about passing a TVP to a UDF.